# How use elastic in laravel app for search without eloquent?

Tags: laravel, elasticsearch

I have a elastic instance where data format and insert by an other application.
I want search data from elastic with my laravel app without use eloquent.
what is the best way for that?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For using a fulltext search you should use [Laravel Scout](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scout). By default Laravel Scout is only shipped with one connector - Algolia. But you can write your own connector to any search engine preferred. There is a section in the Laravel Scout docs about [custom search engines](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scout#custom-engines).

There already seems to be a working package [babenkoivan/elastic-scout-driver](https://github.com/babenkoivan/elastic-scout-driver), that connects Laravel Scout to Elastic Search.

Comment: It work without eloquent and database? I need to use elastic without interaction with my database, just search in elastic index.